# WordPress: special characters in filenames

Tags: wordpress, character-encoding

I named a file as for instance `Glacière_Service-de-lEducation-Ambassade-Chine_map.png`.

The full path should be `http://example.com/.../Glacie%CC%80re_Service-de-lEducation-Ambassade-Chine_map.png`. (`è` = `%CC%80`)

However, the image didn't show up after publishing the post as the path is interpreted as `http://example.com/.../Glaci%C3%A8re_Service-de-lEducation-Ambassade-Chine_map.png`. (`è` = `%C3%A8`)

Why does `è` have different encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the difference:

```
     ↓
Glacie%CC%80re_Service-de-lEducation-Ambassade-Chine_map.png
Glaci%C3%A8re_Service-de-lEducation-Ambassade-Chine_map.png
```

Read about [Normalization Forms](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) in [Unicode® Standard Annex #15: UNICODE NORMALIZATION FORMS](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/).

Unfortunately, I don't speak *PHP*; however, the following *python* example could help:

```
import unicodedata,urllib
from urllib import parse

x = unicodedata.lookup('Latin Small Letter E With Grave')
print(x, len(x))

y = unicodedata.normalize( 'NFKD', x)
print(y, len(y))

for char in (x + ' ' + y):
  print(char, urllib.parse.quote(char, safe='/'),unicodedata.name(char, '?'))
```

**Result**:

```
==> python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import unicodedata,urllib
>>> from urllib import parse
>>>
>>> x = unicodedata.lookup('Latin Small Letter E With Grave')
>>> print(x, len(x))
è 1
>>>
>>> y = unicodedata.normalize( 'NFKD', x)
>>> print(y, len(y))
è 2
>>>
>>> for char in (x + ' ' + y):
...   print(char, urllib.parse.quote(char, safe='/'),unicodedata.name(char, '?'))
...
è %C3%A8 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE
  %20 SPACE
e e LATIN SMALL LETTER E
̀ %CC%80 COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT
>>>
>>>
```

**Result screenshot** added as I can't prevent `NFKC` normalization of the `` e` 2 `` string in above code sample, see result of `print(y, len(y))`:

[image: python example]